# How to add function body at runtime in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a class in which there are some functions. The body of those functions are almost same. Below is the implementation of the class.

```
export class MyClass {
   //constructor code

   private commandingController?:IBaseCommandingController;

   private async getCommandingController()
   {
       if(this.commandingController !== undefined) return this.commandingController;
       this.commandingController = await someAsyncCall();
       return this.commandingController;
   }
   
   private onInsert() = async(arg : InsertArguement) => {
       const commanding = await this.getCommandingController();
       commanding.onInsert(arg);
   };
   private onDelete() = async(arg : DeleteArguement) => {
       const commanding = await this.getCommandingController();
       commanding.onDelete(arg);
   };
   private onUpdate() = async(arg: UpdateAruement) => {
       const commanding = await this.getCommandingController();
       commanding.onUpdate(arg);
   }
   // many more functions like this
}
```

There are 10-12 functions like this and in future there is possibility this will increase in future.

Now instead of adding those 2 lines in every function I wanted that I write a function which will wrap those 2 lines automatically in all my function. Something like this:

```
export class MyClass {
   //constructor code
   constructor(args: any)
   {
       //some other constructor logic;

       //From the below call those 2 lines will be added to all my functions
       wrapBody();
   }
   private commandingController?:IBaseCommandingController;

   private async getCommandingController()
   {
       if(commandingController !== undefined) return this.commandingController;
       this.commandingController = await someAsyncCall();
       return this.commandingController;
   }
   
   private wrapBody() = () => {// Here I will add those 2 lines to every function and return 
   it}; 
   private onInsert() = async(_arg : InsertArguement) => {};
   private onDelete() = async(_arg : DeleteArguement) => {};
   private onUpdate() = async(_arg: UpdateAruement) => {}
   // many more functions like this
}
```

So my question is what should I write in to get this done. I have tried this:

```
private wrapBody() {
    const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter((item) => typeof this[item] === 'function' && item !== 'wrapBody' && item !== 'getCommandingController');
    methods.forEach((functionName) => {
      this[functionName] = this.functionBody(functionName);
    });
  }
private functionBody = (functionName: any, _args: any[]) => {
    return async () => {
      const commanding = await this.initializeCommandingController();
      commanding[functionName](_args);
    };
  };
```

In the above code, I am getting 2 errors. 1st one is I need to pass 2 arguments to functionBody. But I am not able to do because I am not sure how to get arguments of a function in TypeScript.

Second I am getting error in line `commanding[functionName](_args);`

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'IBaseCommandingController'.

Can someone suggest what should I do to solve these 2 errors?

Comment: By the time this question gets answered, you could have written all of those functions out. With documentation. Twice. :-P

Comment: @HereticMonkey lol. Is this is even possible what I am trying to do or not?

Comment: I have no idea. Probably? Meh, seems like overengineering to get around a having to copy paste a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wEDEbW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.